# How do I stop my PS controller from powering off when I press the face buttons?

Tags: controllers

My controller turns off when I press "o" or "x", then it goes to a screen that says "press the PS button to use the controller", then it comes back on after a couple of seconds.

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Try resetting it.

Comment: Is it just o and x? Does this happen with any other buttons?

Answer (score -1):

This probably means that this is not your 1st player controller or it's not set up as the 1st player controller.
I might be able to tell you more if you tell me when this is happening.